# uninitialized constant API::V1::UserController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, rest, rails-api

I know there are already a lot of questions about this on stackoverflow, but none of them works in my case.

In my **routes.rb**

```
Exer9::Application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
        namespace :v1 do
            resources :users
        end
    end
  end
```

**exer9/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module v1
     class UsersController < ApplicationController

      # GET /user
      # GET /user.json
      def index
        @users = User.all

        render json: @users
      end

      def new
      end

      def update
      end
      # GET /user/1
      # GET /user/1.json
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        render json: @user
      end

      def create
        @user = User.new(params[:user])

        if @user.save
          render json: @user
        else
          render json: @user.errors
        end

      end

      def delete
      end

      def destroy
      end
end
end
end
```

**Update**

This is my ApplicationController file

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

The error message that I get is:

```
superclass mismatch for class UsersController

Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
3
4
5
6


     class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

      # GET /user
      # GET /user.json
      def index

Rails.root: /home/steven/Desktop/weekly-exercises/exer9

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>
```

'

Any help here is really appreciated!

Comment: Do you have another UsersController in app/controller/users_controller.rb?

Answer (score 1):

Use shorter syntax, like:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  # your code goes here
end
```

Also, do you restart rails server after renaming classes and files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your folder structure is correct:

`users_controller.rb`

should be found:

`app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb`

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this

In routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1 , default: true) do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

In controller

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController
  # Your code here
end
```